# Understanding the method and object calls

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand how this piece of code all work together. While testing, in tomcat i see that when the device receives the signal, i get the msg "==Deleted all data @ + uri". The tablet essentially receives a signal from the computer to begin this process of wiping. As soon as it gets the signal and initializes connection this is displayed on tomcat and then it begins wipe. How does it do this wipe?

```
DSer.java
public abstract class DSer implements Wipeable{
protected void clearExistingData(ContextWrapper cw) {
    this.clearExistingData(cw, getContentURI());            
}

protected void clearExistingData(ContextWrapper cw, Uri uri) {
    cw.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
    Log.d("DataSerializer", "== Deleted all data @" + uri);
}

@Override
public void wipeData(ContextWrapper cw, Vector<DSFileInfo> files) {
    this.clearExistingData(cw);
}

Wipeable.java
import java.util.Vector;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
public interface Wipeable {
public void wipeData(ContextWrapper cw, Vector<DSFileInfo> files);
}
```

Comment: `cw.getContentResolver().delete()`?